# "Current User" Reference In View Logic

Tags: administration, filters, custom-view

Is there a way I'm just missing in my searches that allows you to compare (example) "Owner ID" versus something like "Current User ID" in a View (where you do NOT have formula access)?

**Effectively:**

```
if( OwnerID != $User.ID , true, false )
```

but within the confines of the filtering allowed in a View (Lead, Account, Opportunity, etc)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom formula field on the object, then filter on that custom formula field in the list view.. Not ideal I know, would be nice to do it directly in the list view setup.

Comment: I have done this in many orgs, something like: IF(Userinfo.getuserid==ownerid,1,0) then filter on the records in the listview where the formula field =1. This works for every user.

Comment: I'm selecting this as the Answer as it's "right" (annoying, having dedicated formula field, but se la vi).

Answer (score 0):

For owner Id **only** you can do it by selecting "My Leads" etc. (this option is not available if you're building a view for a detail in master-detail relationship because OwnerId disappears).

If you have custom lookups to User or want to have say dynamic "created by me" without formulas - no idea :/

[image]